# How to make TinyMCE generate HTML5-compliant code?

Tags: html, wysiwyg, w3c

How can one ensure that HTML code generated from the TinyMCE plugin be HTML5 compliant according to the W3C specification?

For example, image code such as

```
<img height="50" width="100" src="img.png/>
```

will be generated.

Can it be configured so that the following would be created instead?

```
<img style='height:50px;width:100px' src='img.png'/>
```

Comment: Which part is not HTML5 compliant?

Comment: Does it really generate the first line, without the `"`, or is this your typo?